# Downgrading C/C++ compiler on Fedora 23 to a MATLAB R2016a-compatible compiler

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, fedora, fedora-23

I would like to build MEX functions from C/C++ source code to enable MATLAB script access, but my current version of Fedora has a newer and incompatible GCC. I have tried removing the installed GCC and installing a 4.7.x version of GCC using sudo dnf gcc-4.7.x (with x = [1, 2, 3, 4]), but it seems that none of those versions are hosted on the Fedora package repositories.

Is there any other way to install older versions of GCC on the newer Fedora versions?

Comment: Are you actually having issues compiling the mex files or is it successfully compiling them and just showing a warning. If it's the later than you're likely OK to ignore it.

Comment: @Suever the issue is with compiling the mex files themselves. The newer versions of GCC are incompatible with MATLAB.

Comment: Right. You didn't answer my question. Did the MATLAB issue a warning when you try to compile them or were there actual errors? MATLAB will gladly compile using a non-supported version of GCC it'll just give you a warning when doing so.

Comment: I believe they were actual errors, not mere warnings. It said something like "Error using mex: No supported compiler or SDK was found"

Comment: Ok then that makes sense, just wanted clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @Suever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to download gcc source, and compile gcc yourself. Fedora repositories are release-specific. gccs from earlier releases of Fedora are not included in subsequent releases of Fedora.

Although it's possible to download earlier versions of gcc manually, from the appropriate release of Fedora, it is unlikely that rpm will agree to install it, due to version conflicts. It's possible that someone will helpfully suggest using `--force` to force-install an incompatible version of gcc. Such advice, alas, is fairly likely to result in an unbootable brick.

So the only practical answer is to download and build gcc yourself; with a custom configuration that installs gcc into a non-default location, in order to avoid overwriting the system-installed `libstdc++`. Not a trivial task, having done this myself, some years ago.

TL;DR: if you have to ask such a question, it's not possible.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response. I am relatively a beginner with Linux and, if it's not too much to ask, do you know if there are any guides on how to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid there are no "guides" of any kind. The short, and rough answer is that it's unlikely that a "beginner" will be able to accomplish the task of building a custom configuration of gcc. Like I said, this is not a trivial task. For two senior developers, with a combined 40 years of experience in C++ and Linux engineering, the task of producing a reproducible custom build of gcc took a couple of weeks to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

---

1) You can have as many versions of gcc/g++ as you want, installed at the same time.  2) Not a good idea to remove the system compiler.

Gcc-4.7 : Simple, install [the required packages] from the "Redhat devtoolset-1.1"  http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/ → → # `wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-devtoolset.repo http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/devtoolset/slc6-devtoolset.repo`

The devtoolset-1.1 and devtoolset-2 were created for RHEL6, so we have to install some old files for devtoolset-(1.1) : `compat-gmp-4.3.1-11.fc23.x86_64.rpm`, and  `compat-mpfr-2.4.1-7.fc23.x86_64.rpm` .... Links : compat-gmp https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbTBSS21jdWlvRXM/view?usp=sharing - compat-mpfr https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOG8wYU1sY0lkQWc/view?usp=sharing

Then you can install the 4 packages from devtoolset-1.1 (gcc-c++ and dependencies,,, gcc etc.) with # `dnf install --nogpgcheck devtoolset-1.1-gcc-c++`

Enabling gcc-4.7 : $ `scl enable devtoolset-1.1 bash` ... and `gcc -v` will say "gcc version 4.7.2" ( The setting is valid until you exit the terminal.)

---

Comment: thanks I'll try this tomorrow when I get access to my Linux machine.